# PySpark df.toPandas() throws error "org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Memory was leaked by query. Memory leaked: (376832)"

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, memory-leaks

Using PySpark, I am attempting to convert a spark `DataFrame` to a pandas `DataFrame` using the following:

```py
# Enable Arrow-based columnar data transfers
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")

data.toPandas()
```

I am getting the error "`org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Memory was leaked by query. Memory leaked: (376832)`", but I'm not sure why this error occurs. It occurs even on a subset of `data` with only 10 rows. Running without `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")` has no effect on the error I receive.

Full error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [20]:
Line 8:     data.toPandas()

File c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Java\runtime\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\pandas\conversion.py, in toPandas:
Line 108:   batches = self.toDF(*tmp_column_names)._collect_as_arrow()

File c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Java\runtime\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\pandas\conversion.py, in _collect_as_arrow:
Line 244:   jsocket_auth_server.getResult()

File c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Java\runtime\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py, in __call__:
Line 1305:  answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)

File c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Java\runtime\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py, in deco:
Line 128:   return f(*a, **kw)

File c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Java\runtime\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py, in get_return_value:
Line 328:   format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o204.getResult.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.security.SocketAuthServer.getResult(SocketAuthServer.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.security.SocketAuthServer.getResult(SocketAuthServer.scala:84)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 26.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 26.0 (TID 26, <user>, executor driver): org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Memory was leaked by query. Memory leaked: (376832)
Allocator(toBatchIterator) 0/376832/376832/9223372036854775807 (res/actual/peak/limit)


Previous exception in task: sun.misc.Unsafe or java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int) not available
    io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.directBuffer(PlatformDependent.java:490)
    io.netty.buffer.NettyArrowBuf.getDirectBuffer(NettyArrowBuf.java:243)
    io.netty.buffer.NettyArrowBuf.nioBuffer(NettyArrowBuf.java:233)
    io.netty.buffer.ArrowBuf.nioBuffer(ArrowBuf.java:245)
    org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.ArrowRecordBatch.computeBodyLength(ArrowRecordBatch.java:222)
    org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageSerializer.serialize(MessageSerializer.java:240)
    org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageSerializer.serialize(MessageSerializer.java:226)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.$anonfun$next$1(ArrowConverters.scala:118)
    scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.next(ArrowConverters.scala:121)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.next(ArrowConverters.scala:97)
    scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.foreach(ArrowConverters.scala:97)
    scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
    scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
    scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
    scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:315)
    scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.to(ArrowConverters.scala:97)
    scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
    scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.toBuffer(ArrowConverters.scala:97)
    scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:294)
    scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.toArray(ArrowConverters.scala:97)
    org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectAsArrowToPython$6(Dataset.scala:3562)
    org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$6(SparkContext.scala:2193)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
    org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.invokeListeners(TaskContextImpl.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2008)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2239)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2188)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2177)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectAsArrowToPython$5(Dataset.scala:3560)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectAsArrowToPython$2(Dataset.scala:3564)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectAsArrowToPython$2$adapted(Dataset.scala:3541)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3618)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3616)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectAsArrowToPython$1(Dataset.scala:3541)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectAsArrowToPython$1$adapted(Dataset.scala:3540)
    at org.apache.spark.security.SocketAuthServer$.$anonfun$serveToStream$2(SocketAuthServer.scala:130)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.security.SocketAuthServer$.$anonfun$serveToStream$1(SocketAuthServer.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.security.SocketAuthServer$.$anonfun$serveToStream$1$adapted(SocketAuthServer.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.security.SocketFuncServer.handleConnection(SocketAuthServer.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.security.SocketFuncServer.handleConnection(SocketAuthServer.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.security.SocketAuthServer$$anon$1.$anonfun$run$1(SocketAuthServer.scala:60)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.security.SocketAuthServer$$anon$1.run(SocketAuthServer.scala:60)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Memory was leaked by query. Memory leaked: (376832)
Allocator(toBatchIterator) 0/376832/376832/9223372036854775807 (res/actual/peak/limit)


Previous exception in task: sun.misc.Unsafe or java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int) not available
    io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.directBuffer(PlatformDependent.java:490)
    io.netty.buffer.NettyArrowBuf.getDirectBuffer(NettyArrowBuf.java:243)
    io.netty.buffer.NettyArrowBuf.nioBuffer(NettyArrowBuf.java:233)
    io.netty.buffer.ArrowBuf.nioBuffer(ArrowBuf.java:245)
    org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.ArrowRecordBatch.computeBodyLength(ArrowRecordBatch.java:222)
    org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageSerializer.serialize(MessageSerializer.java:240)
    org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageSerializer.serialize(MessageSerializer.java:226)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.$anonfun$next$1(ArrowConverters.scala:118)
    scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.next(ArrowConverters.scala:121)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.next(ArrowConverters.scala:97)
    scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.foreach(ArrowConverters.scala:97)
    scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
    scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
    scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:105)
    scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to(TraversableOnce.scala:315)
    scala.collection.TraversableOnce.to$(TraversableOnce.scala:313)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.to(ArrowConverters.scala:97)
    scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
    scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toBuffer$(TraversableOnce.scala:307)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.toBuffer(ArrowConverters.scala:97)
    scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:294)
    scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.arrow.ArrowConverters$$anon$1.toArray(ArrowConverters.scala:97)
    org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectAsArrowToPython$6(Dataset.scala:3562)
    org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$6(SparkContext.scala:2193)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
    org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.invokeListeners(TaskContextImpl.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any hints or suggestions on how to resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: We are seeing similar issue.  Application fails; many of the containers have stderr with memory leak errors:  ```22/01/29 20:24:27 ERROR BaseAllocator: Memory was leaked by query. Memory leaked: (4194304)
Allocator(stdin reader for /usr/bin/python3) 0/4194304/4194304/9223372036854775807 (res/actual/peak/limit)
... ...
22/01/29 20:24:28 ERROR TaskContextImpl: Error in TaskCompletionListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Memory was leaked by query. Memory leaked: (4194304)
Allocator(stdin reader for /usr/bin/python3) 0/4194304/4194304/9223372036854775807 (res/actual/peak/limit)```

Comment: I found the leak error message in Apache Arrow source code:  https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/f0e0cfb520ef30f2ef9240b59cecb5482c3f70c7/java/memory/memory-core/src/main/java/org/apache/arrow/memory/BaseAllocator.java#L434-L435

Comment: Hey, I did resolve this by upgrading the version of spark, will answer my own question below in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out the older version of Spark I was on was the problem. Upgrading Spark resolved the issue for me. You could use the SPARK_HOME env variable to try different version(s):

```py
# 1. get spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz from https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.1.1/
# (You can get different version, this one worked for me, newer might be better for you - version with log4j fix might be available now)
# 2. open git bash, then:
# >> cd <spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz location>
# >> tar xzvf spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
# 3. set system environment variable (used by spark_esri):
# SPARK_HOME: <path/to/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7>
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = r"C:\spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7"
```

Comment: From which to which version have you switched? We see the same error in Spark 3.1.1 when using toPandas to convert a spark DF.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the very late response! The version is in the code sample in the comment you replied to, 3.1.1.

We ended up not upgrading because the issue was with Java 11 and could be fixed with passing a flag.

Added flag -Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true to Spark to pass to JVM when starting up. This is what [Spark recommends](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/#downloading) doing if you are using certain versions of Spark and Java

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded pyspark to newest version then its fixed.

```
pip install pyspark==3.4.1
```